# What can I change in my Question to "unclose" it?

Tags: discussion

Here is my Question : (A) [Perl 5.34 not available via Windows regular installer](https://superuser.com/questions/1727108/perl-5-34-not-available-via-windows-regular-installer)

It is the Exact same as these two:
(B) [Download installer for old version of Git](https://superuser.com/questions/966998/download-installer-for-old-version-of-git?rq=1)
(C) [How to install Google Chrome completely offline and without checking for new version?](https://superuser.com/questions/746043/how-to-install-google-chrome-completely-offline-and-without-checking-for-new-ver?rq=1)

While my Q (A) is about Perl, (B) is about Git & (C) is about Google Chrome; Otherwise, all 3 are similar, looking to get Download-and-Install Binaries on Windows servers without Internet Access.

I am not sure what I can change in my Question to "unclose" it. Suggestions ? Thoughts ?

Comment: (B) is an old question that is off topic by current on-topic rules. (C) is different in that the user already has downloaded the software needed and is not looking to locate it on the net.

Comment: And isn't this off-topic too :-)

Comment: Not off-topic , @RohitGupta ; This Meta Q had the unwanted "side effect" of closing the git Q (( and strangely, closing and reopening the Google Chrome Q )) and has also received a great Answer !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bit of a tough one.  *Technically*, given that there are multiple installers (and you mention that in your questions), it can be seen as *"[asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation.](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)"*

That said, there's the "letter of the law" and the "spirit of the law".  Your question, to me, seems completely fair.  The purpose of restricting questions about "product recommendations" is (as the close reason states) to avoid subjective "opinion-based" answers.  Those types of questions end up end "discussions" or "multiple answers where ever answer is equally valid."  I absolutely agree that Stack Exchange sites are not well suited for *that* type of question.

However, yours seems to fit more into the [allowed subjective questions](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) category:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive.

Your question, albeit about a "software recommendation", certainly is set up to invite practical, constructive answers.

All that said, I doubt we're going to get it reopened based on *that*.

Personally, I'd say this is a question better suited for Stack Overflow, since it is about:

> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Still, it could be seen as a request for an off-site resource and closed *there* for that reason, so here's how I'd reword it *just to be sure*:

---

###### How to install ActiveState Perl 5.34 on Windows without an Internet connection?

[ActiveState](https://www.activestate.com/products/perl/) used to have Perl Installers that could be downloaded and then installed on Windows.  The installation step could be completed without Internet connectivity. The latest versions (e.g. Perl 5.34 or Perl 5.36) seem to only be installable via the State tool, which requires an Internet connection.

I need 5.34, so I'm not able to use [StrawBerry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/) since its latest version is 5.32 and nothing newer.

[perl.com's Windows' links](https://www.perl.org/get.html#win32) only point to ActiveState & StrawBerry, so I'm assuming that ActiveState is my only option for 5.34.

*Question: Without compiling from source, how can I install Perl 5.34 on Windows Server without an Internet connection? Is this possible?*

---

So here's the thing -- If there's another alternative installer that might have that capability (and I think we both doubt there is), someone's probably going to mention it, even though you don't *specifically* ask for a recommendation on that topic.

While you could edit that here to make it (IMHO) on-topic, I'd recommend reposting on Stack Overflow since:

- It's arguably *more* on-topic there as a question "unique to programming"
- It will be faster than getting 5 reopen votes here on Super User after fixing the question.